# Laravel do not show data if relationship is null

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have this code:

```
 $rightsRequests = $this->company->rightsRequests()
            ->orderBy('created_at','DESC')
            ->with(['post' => function($q){
                $q->where('posts.status','!=',100);
            },'userWhoRequested'])
            ->get();
```

I am filtering data that if a relationship "posts" has a status of `100` it will make the `posts` object  `null`. So something like this: `"posts" : null`.

That query is showing these data:

```
[
   {
      "post_id":57,
      "network_id":2,
      "source_id":3,
      "feed_id":2,

      "user_who_requested":{
         "id":6,
         "notification":2,

      },
      "post":null
   },
   {
      "post_id":57,
      "network_id":2,
      "source_id":3,
      "feed_id":2,
      "user_who_requested":{
         "id":6,
         "notification":2,
      },

      "post":{
         "id":58,
         "network_id":2,
         "status":1,

      }
   }
]
```

How can i not show data if the relationship `posts` is `100` or should i say `null`? So on the example output, it should not display that first key because the `posts` is null. So it should just display this data since the `posts` is not null:

```
[
   {
      "post_id":57,
      "network_id":2,
      "source_id":3,
      "feed_id":2,
      "user_who_requested":{
         "id":6,
         "notification":2,
      },

      "post":{
         "id":58,
         "network_id":2,
         "status":1,

      }
   }
]
```

How can i do that in the eloquent query?

I'm having a hard time explaining, sorry!

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter by the lack of existence of the `post` relationship based on a condition:

```
$rightsRequests = $this->company->rightsRequests()
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
    ->with('post')
    ->whereDoesntHave('post', function ($query) {
        $query->where('posts.status', 100);
    })->get();
```

You don't need to constrain the eager load because we are already filtering out the records that have a `post` where `status = 100` with the `whereHas`/`whereDoesntHave`.

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Eloquent - Relationships - Querying Relationship Absence](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence) `whereDoesntHave`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue a while back. You can use the eloquent `whereHas` method. If the relationship has a null value it will not show. Only the ones where a value exists would show.

Your code would look like this:

```
$rightsRequests = $this->company->rightsRequests()
        ->orderBy('created_at','DESC')
        ->whereHas('post')
        ->with(['post' => function($q){
            $q->where('posts.status','!=',100);
        },'userWhoRequested'])
        ->get();
```

Here's a reference to a [laracrast discussion](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-exclude-models-with-relation-data-of-null) where I got my solution.